# Pass array of CimInstance to CimMethod

Tags: powershell, wmi

I am working with WMI API through Cim cmdlets. The problem is that I can't figure out how to pass wmi object to wmi method that accepts array of wmi objects.

Here are method parameters definition:

```
Name                                            CimType Qualifiers
----                                            ------- ----------
Path                                             String {ID, in}
Permissions                               InstanceArray {EmbeddedInstance, ID, in}
ResetChildren                                   Boolean {ID, in}
```

`Path` and `ResetChildren` are simple parameters. They accepts simple values like `"/path"` and `$true` respectively. But I have troubles with `Permissions` parameter.

Here is my code

```
#Acquiring object that I want to pass to method
$group = Get-CimInstance -Namespace "root\VisualSVN" -ClassName VisualSVN_Group -Filter "Name='Readers'"

#Acquiring object which method will be called
$repositories = Get-CimInstance -Namespace "root\VisualSVN" -ClassName VisualSVN_Repository

#Preparing method arguments
$args = @{
    Path = "/";
    Permissions = @($group[0]); #Trouble here
    ResetChildren = $true
}

#Invoking method with arguments
Invoke-CimMethod -InputObject ($repositories[0]) -MethodName SetSecurity -Arguments $args
```

Execution of this code will result in error:

```
Invoke-CimMethod : Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimInstance' to type 'M
icrosoft.Management.Infrastructure.Native.InstanceHandle'.
Parameter name: value
At C:\somepath\script1.ps1:11 char:1
+ Invoke-CimMethod -InputObject ($repositories[0]) -MethodName SetSecurity -Argume ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Invoke-CimMethod], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimCmdlets.Invoke
   CimMethodCommand
```

If you change code

```
Permissions = @($group[0]); #Trouble here
```

To code

```
Permissions = $group; #Trouble here
```

Then error message will also change:

```
Invoke-CimMethod : Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.Native.InstanceHandle'
to type 'System.Collections.IList'.
Parameter name: value
At C:\somepath\script1.ps1:11 char:1
+ Invoke-CimMethod -InputObject ($repositories[0]) -MethodName SetSecurity -Argume ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Invoke-CimMethod], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimCmdlets.Invoke
   CimMethodCommand
```

Any ideas how to pass `$group` to method properly?

Comment: I don’t have VisualSVN Installed, so can’t test this, but does your “$group[0]“ object have a Handle property? If yes, what about passing “$group[0].Handle“?

Comment: I think that this trouble is not related directly to VisualSVN. So you can reproduce it with any WMI method that have similar signature. Method must accept array of some WMI objects. Unfortunately my “$group[0]“ doesn't have neither Handle property nor something related to InstanceHandle. InstanceHandle class is related to internal implementation details and doesn't have any public documentation. I guess that exception is throwing when PowerShell is doing some magic to convert from PowerShell internal WMI object representation to pure WMI object.

Comment: I do understand that this is not a VisualSVN issue, it would just be nice to reproduce the error.  Here is another example  [link]http://powershell.com/cs/forums/p/13888/26108.aspx. Unfortunately I can't reproduced it either. One ‘hint’ that I have found is “The CIM cmdlets return inert objects” ([link]http://blogs.msmvps.com/richardsiddaway/category/powershellandwmi/page/4/) It explains that objects returned by get-cmistance are “inert” copies of WMI objects without any methods. I would try to rewrite the code using Get-WmiObject and see if you can call the method directly.

Comment: I wrote script that searches computer for all WMI methods that accepts array of objects. [Get-Methods.ps1](https://github.com/r0t0r-r0t0r/AdministrationScripts/blob/master/Get-Methods.ps1). Hope this help you reproduce situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had exactly same problem with `VisualSVN_Repository::SetSecurity` method.

When working with CIM method arguments, you must cast **ANY array arguments** to **`[CimInstance[]]`**.

For example, this worked for me:

```
$Everyone = Get-CimInstance -Namespace root/VisualSVN -ClassName VisualSVN_Everyone
# Grant Everyone a Read/Write access:
$AccessRule = New-CimInstance -Namespace root/VisualSVN -ClassName VisualSVN_PermissionEntry -ClientOnly -Property @{ Account = $Everyone; AccessLevel = [UInt32]2 }
$SvnRepo = Get-CimInstance -Namespace root/VisualSVN -ClassName VisualSVN_Repository -Filter "Name='MY_REPOSITORY_NAME'"

Invoke-CimMethod -InputObject $SvnRepo -MethodName SetSecurity -Arguments @{ 
    Path = '/';
    Permissions = [CimInstance[]]$AccessRule;
    ResetChildren = $true
} | Out-Null
```

You must cast array argument to `[CimInstance[]]` even when it is just a single item.

**P.S.:** Be careful with `Ref` array arguments too: you must first cast it to `[CimInstance[]]` and then to `[ref[]]`. For example, when calling `VisualSVN_Group::Create` method:

```
[CimInstance[]] $SvnUsers = [CimInstance[]]($ArrayOf_VisualSVN_User_Objects)

Invoke-CimMethod -ClassName VisualSVN_Group -Namespace root/VisualSVN -MethodName Create -Arguments @{
    Members = [ref[]]$SvnUsers;
    Name = 'MY_NEW_GROUP_NAME'
} | Out-Null
```

See also: [Tip#5: Passing ref and embedded instances on PowerShell Blog.](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/cim-cmdlets-some-tips-tricks/#tip5-passing-ref-and-embedded-instances)

Answer (score 0):

If you had a repro that did not rely on software I do not have installed, I could answer definitively, so I will make my best attempt based on what I can infer from your question.

To make what you are assigning to `Permissions` an array, and you are only assigning one value, use a comma in front.

`Permissions = ,$group`

Here is some sample script and the output to demonstrate.

**Script**

```
$var1 = "any value"
$var2 = ,$var1

$var1.GetType()
$var2.GetType()
$var2.Count
$var2[0]
```

**Output**

```
IsPublic IsSerial Name      BaseType
-------- -------- ----      --------
True     True     String    System.Object
True     True     Object[]  System.Array
1
any value
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution (it worked for me with a similar issue that led me here) based on the 'hint' that CIM are inert objects.  In my case it was installing SCCM updates in a scripted manner while allowing for reboots if the updates required them, and stopping if the entire process took more than a certain amount of time (to not go past the available maintenance window).

I was passing a CIMUpdate object through to a powershell function to perform the update to allow for rebooting if necessary between updates (Perform a single update at a time, verify if reboot is needed, then try the next update).

The CIM object was giving a Type Mismatch error when forcing it to cast as `[CIMInstance[]]`, and if not casting at all I would get the same `Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimInstance' to type 'Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.Native.InstanceHandle'` error message.

Solution was to use that `CIMUpdate` and re-query to get a `live` version of the object within the function and then use that new object as the argument to the CIMMethod.

Answer (score 0):

as of now, it works for me , the case I am working on is passing `New-ScheduledTaskTrigger` instance to a function.

I am passing a `CimInstance` to a function and receiving it as `PSCustomObject` type.

1. Send `CimInstance` receive as [PSCustomObject] -> at target it remains `CimInstance` object type
2. Send `CimInstance`  receive as [CimInstance] -> at target it remains `CimInstance` object type
3. Send `CimInstance`  receive as [CimInstance[]] -> at target it turn to `CimInstance` array type